# Настройка переименовывания пользователем элементов из АПИ Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть очень глупый вопрос: мне нужно в приложении настроить возможность переименовать названия на те, которые хочет пользователь. Названия по умолчанию (еще не измененные пользователем) идут из АПИ, путем гугления выяснил, что моя задача решается путем использования операции put-request-а. Проблема в том, что АПИ принадлежит не мне и разработчики АПИ настоятельно не рекомендуют вообще вносить какие-либо изменения в работу, то есть не использовать ни put, ни post запросы, только get.

Можно ли во Flutter как-то это обойти? Ну, например, загружать в локальную БД по типу Hive те названия, которые изменил пользователь на свое усмотрение или использовать, например, shared prefernces? Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей и знает, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Можно подробней, названия чего?

Comment: @nazarpunk например, названий книг. Есть названия, которые идут из АПИ, а пользователь, допустим, хочет поменять какое-то из названий и чтобы это название, измененное им, так и оставалось в списке книжек

Comment: _«пользователь, допустим, хочет поменять какое-то из названий и чтобы это название, измененное им, так и оставалось в списке книжек»_ - используй `Map` для трансляции апишных данных в пользовательские. Конечно же, строковые ключи нужно будет как-то нормализовать, исходя из характера строковой инфы. А хранение этих пользовательских данных, может быть где угодно (это не суть важный фактор). Еще, можно попробовать использовать какие-нибудь пакеты для локализации, ведь они делают по сути то же самое - надо только найти ту реализацию, которая позволяет менять содержимое словаря в рантайме.

Comment: А вы в API из флаттера стучитесь или через свой сервер?

Comment: @nazarpunk из Флаттера стучусь

Comment: @inkwelll075 если у книжек есть уникальный `id`, то можете тупо храить в `shared prefernces`, а если нужно работать со строками, то @yar85 уже всё описал.

Comment: @nazarpunk спасибо, да у книжек есть свой уникальный айдишник. Думаю, так и сделаю.